# How to stop the keyboard "Send" button from making the keyboard hide?

Tags: keyboard, uitextfield, xcode8, textfield

I use Objective C

```
   -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField    
 {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:TRUE];
self.chat.frame = CGRectMake(self.chat.frame.origin.x, self.chat.frame.origin.y -255., self.chat.frame.size.width, self.chat.frame.size.height);

 self.chit.frame = CGRectMake(self.chit.frame.origin.x, self.chit.frame.origin.y -255., self.chit.frame.size.width, self.chit.frame.size.height);

 self.button.frame = CGRectMake(self.button.frame.origin.x, self.button.frame.origin.y -255., self.button.frame.size.width, self.button.frame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];
 }

 -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField  
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:TRUE];
self.chat.frame = CGRectMake(self.chat.frame.origin.x, self.chat.frame.origin.y +255., self.chat.frame.size.width, self.chat.frame.size.height);

self.chit.frame = CGRectMake(self.chit.frame.origin.x, self.chit.frame.origin.y +255., self.chit.frame.size.width, self.chit.frame.size.height);

 self.button.frame = CGRectMake(self.button.frame.origin.x, self.button.frame.origin.y +255., self.button.frame.size.width, self.button.frame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This code lets the Keyboard pop up along with the UITextField every time I click on the UITextField. I also used ResignFirstResponder.

However, on my keyboard is a SEND button. When I click on the SEND button, the Keyboard goes back down. How do I make the SEND button stop hiding the keyboard?